# Windows Installer - Assembly is not removed from GAC during uninstallation

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installation

I have created an MSI using VS 2010 to install web service. During the installation one project DLL is being added to GAC.

But when I uninstall the service DLL added to GAC is not being removed. This issue exists in Windows Server 2003, but this works fine in Win 7 machine.

Any clue what is causing this?

Comment: How are you removing it?

Comment: Im not doing anything explicitly to remove it from GAC. Since im adding it to GAC through MSI when its uninstalled it should be removed from GAC unless its marked as Premanent.

Comment: That seems right. Do you have any real issues with it not beeing removed correctly? Did you look into the uninstall log? Does it say something?

Comment: Yes i have issue, because when i install a latest version of the service its not replacing the previous version of dlls in the GAC. Where i can find the uninstall log ?

Comment: I think you can tell the MSI to create one - i dont know where they are stored by default.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Gacutil to uninstall the dll from Assembly manually.

gacutil /u hello.dll

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: GACUtil is not available on "normal" computers and it's not allowed to redistribute it.

Comment: Not correct...its a part of Windows SDK.
Get it from Microsoft.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24826